# Cisco Digital Optical Monitoring Command

Tags: cisco-commands, optics, optical

Can some tell me what for monitoring optical power on my 7200 series router .
The interface has a SFP 1000BASE-LX.

sh int gig0/0 transceiver ,doesnt give me the required information( Optical power in dBm)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the part number to determine SFP compatibility. This is from 
[Digital Optical Monitoring - DOM](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/75181/digital-optical-monitoring-dom), which has a link to the compatibility matrix:

> **DOM Support on Cisco Transeivers**
>
> Not all transceivers support DOM, a list of capable transceivers is
>   available at:
>
> [DOM compability Matrix](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/compatibility/matrix/OL_8031.html)
>
> **How to use DOM**
>
> Following command can be used to turn on/off DOM for all transceivers
>   type in the system
>
> ```
> Router(config)#transceiver type all
> Router(config-xcvr-type)#monitoring
> Router(config-xcvr-type)#end
> ```
>
> Once enabled, DOM can be accessed via CLI using `show interface transceiver` command